# Get filename as UTF-8? (ä,ü,ö ... is always '?')

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I have to read the name of some files and put them in a list as a string. Its not so hard I just have some Problems with some characters like ä,ö,ü ... they are always as a '?' in my string.

Whats the Problem? Well the encoding. Ok this should be easy... thats what i thought. So I tried to use functions like:

`new String(insert.getBytes("UTF-8")`
or
`new String(insert.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")`
because the most of the files are ISO-8859-1

Its not helping. This is my code:

```
...
File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();
String insert;
for(File f : fileList) {
...
insert=f.getName().substring(0,f.getName().length()-4);
                insert=insert.charAt(0)+insert.substring(1,insert.length()).toLowerCase().replaceFirst("([0-9]*(_s?(i)?(_dat)?)*$)", "").replaceFirst("_", " ");
...
System.out.println("test UTF8: " + new String(insert.getBytes("UTF-8"))); //not helping
System.out.println("test ISO , UTF8: " + new String(insert.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")); //not helping
...
names.add(insert);
}
```

At the end there are a lot of strings with '?' characters in my list.
How to fix the problem? And whats the best way if there are not only ISO-8859-1 files? (lets say there are a lot of unknown encoded files)

Thank You!

Comment: Are you reading the filenames from disk or from another file?  There is a preferred OS filename encoding, but if you are getting it from a file with unknown encodings you may be in trouble.

Comment: If you can read the files with a certain encoding (the right one) and write them back to disk and you get no strange characters, then your encoding processing is fine. In that case, is just your console that doesn't have the characters for displaying.

Comment: @mdrg: well, theres a Problem. I have to read the name of the files and then put them into a database. And there are a lot of '?' , that shouldnt be...

Comment: @Lissy: No, you misunderstand. The disk has the right filename, the program has the right filename, the DB might even have the right filenames, but perhaps when you print the filenames to your screen, your screen isn't showing the correct characters.  Of course, if `ls` shows it and `yourprogram` show question marks, that is a problem with yourprogram.  BTW, what OS and filesystem are you running this on?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with whole process? To write the stuff in the database? I tried and in the database there are a lot of '?' I have to convert these strings to an utf8 or something... I thought that would help.

Comment: @Seth Robertson: the files are on a Debian system. BUT and Im sure thats the problem: these files are coming from windows OS (they were made on windows and then got copied to the debian system). And windows is always using some mystical encoding...

Comment: @Lissy: The critical information is still missing.  What does `ls` report when you run it on the files/directory in question?  Does it print the spécíäl characters or does it print ? as well?

Comment: @Lissy: Then there are two options: the files were incorrectly created when copied to the system and the actual filenames have ? (or are otherwise in an incorrect encoding), or your font cannot display the characters and everything is working properly behind the scenes.  If you are sure the filenames have ä in them, try creating your own filenäme with a special character like that in them.  If `ls` can display that created filename (try copy-paste this `touch filenäme; ls filen*me` command) then the problem is with the copy, probably an encoding problem.

Comment: @Set: Well...this touch is a nice option, maybe not the best but ok ^^ - just one question: what do you mean with "the files were incorrectly created" and "otherwise in an incorrect encoding" - how to create a file incorrectly? or how to get and incorrect encoding? (ok on MS Windows is everything possible, but I would like to know ^^) Thank you

Comment: @Lissy: I have created an answer below with more details, but basically the fault is with the program that created the files.  There are several ways in which this could have been done incorrectly, but without knowing what program created the file (samba mount?  unzip?  ftp?) it would just be idle speculation.

Comment: what program created the file? sftp

Answer (score 3):

Given the extended comments back and forth under the question, it now looks like this is either a font problem or (perhaps more likely) a filename encoding problem.

I asked Lissy to run the following command to let us figure out what the problem is.  If she is sure that the filename contain "ä" in them, but that character does not appear when she `ls` the filename, then this command will tell us whether this is a font or encoding problem.

```
touch filenäme
ls filen*me
```

If this shows "filenäme" in the output of `ls` then we know the problem is with the creation/copy of the files onto this system.  This could happen if the program which created the files didn't realize what the filesystem encoding was or was too stupid to do the right thing.  The `convmv` program will probably be the best way to fix this.

```
convmv -f ENCODING -t utf8 -r .
```

The question is what is the proper encoding.  Possibilities include UTF-16, cp850, or perhaps iso8859-1.  `convmv --list` will show you the list of currently known (to your system) encodings.  Since the listed command above only shows you what it might do, it is safe to run several times with different encodings until you find one which works *for all files*.

If this is a font problem, we'll have to look into that

Comment: Hi. convmv is great! I tried it here on my desktop and it works fine. The problem is: on the sftp server where the files are, there is no convmv and there will be never a convmv, i dont have root.

Comment: @Lissy: My only idea is to write a program which interacts with the FTP server and renames them on the same rules which convmv uses.  Or download everything, delete, convmv, and then re-upload.

Comment: @Lissy: you can compile [it](https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/convmv-1.15.tar.gz) on your home folder by youself.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding of the content of the file name has nothing to do with the encoding of the file name itself.

You should get correct results from `System.out.println(insert)`

If you don't, it means that the shell has a different character encoding that the default character encoding for your system (this rarely happens; it would usually be the result of an explicit command to switch encodings in the shell).

If the file names are displayed correctly when you list the directory in the shell, I would expect them to be displayed correctly without specifying an encoding in your Java program.

---

If the shell is incapable of displaying the character (it is substituting the replacement character 0xFFFD (�) for these unprintable characters), there's nothing you can do from your Java application to change that. You need to change the terminal character encoding, install the right fonts, etc.; that is a operating system issue, not a Java issue.

At the same time, even if your terminal can't display the correct results, the Java program should be handling the character encodings correctly without your intervention.

The library behind the `File` API is figuring out the correct character encoding for your system and doing the necessary decoding into characters. Likewise, the database driver should negotiate with the database to determine the correct encoding, and do any necessary encoding into bytes on behalf of your application.

Comment: if i try out System.out.println(insert) it comes stuff like "F?st"

Comment: if i try it in the terminal with ls -l then "F�st"

Comment: @Lissy: Did you explicitly set the encoding on `System.out`?  If not, that is the problem.  For example, you should have a `stdout = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");` or some such somewhere. You can also often run with `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, but that is technically read-only.

Comment: @tchrist: even if I use new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"); there is an �

Answer (score 1):

Unexpected question marks, spalts, etc in a String are a sign that something somewhere doesn't recognize a particular character when converting from one character set to another.

In your case, the problem could be occurring in a couple of places:

- It could be occurring when your Java program is reading the file names from the directory (in the `dir.listFiles()` call).
- It could be happening when you print the characters to the console stream.

In either case, the root cause is most likely a mismatch between what Java thinks the locale settings should be and the settings that the operating system and/or command shell are using.

As an experiment, try to list a directory containing the problematic file names from the command line.  Do you see question marks or other splats there?

A second experiment to perform is to modify your Java program to dump one of the problem Strings as a sequence of numbers representing the character codes for each of the characters.  Do you see the character codes for an ASCII / Unicode `'?'`.

Comment: Well, yes, but I believe that a `?` is a sure sign that somebody somewhere neglected to raise an exception when they should have.  Don’t ever let something produce a `?`.

Comment: @tchrist the `?` is used as a "replacement character" in well-defined circumstances, and this is a widely used behavior in many applications (shells, web browsers, etc). If needed, in Java, this behavior can be changed to throw an exception, but it isn't the default.

Comment: @erickson: `?` is specifically recommended against; this is one of Java’s flaws.  The Unicode Replacement Character should be used if needed, but it is much better to raise an exception because it shows you are doing something wrong instead of masking the error.

Comment: Java will replace unencodable characters with an encoding of U+FFFD **if** the target encoding can encode U+FFFD. However, most encodings can't. UTF-8, UTF-16, etc., being among the rare exceptions. In cases where the encoding can't encode U+FFFD, then '?' is the usual fallback, because (almost?) every encoding can support it.

Comment: @tchrist - *"...but it is much better to raise an exception ..."*.  I disagree.  Throwing an exception every time there is an unmappable character results in large numbers of documents, etc being inaccessible from Java.  Imagine your web browser refusing to display pages that contained a long dash or a funky quote character that the declared document encoding didn't support.  Bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you wrote:

> @mdrg: well, theres a Problem. I have to read the name of the files and then put them into a database. And there are a lot of '?' , that shouldnt be... – Lissy 27 mins ago

My guess is that the column you're inserting the filenames into specifies US-ASCII as the encoding and replaces characters outside that range with a replacement character, which in your case is the question mark.

So you have to find out the encoding for the column in your database table where you store the filenames. Various products have various syntaxes for retrieving that information.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 1.6 you can use System.console() instead of System.out.println() to display accentuated characters to console.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]){
   String s = "caractères français :  à é \u00e9"; // Unicode for "é"
   System.console().writer().println(s);
  }
}
```

and the output is

```
C:\temp>java Test
caractères français :  à é é
```