# Convert ISO8859 String to UTF8? ÄÖÜ => ÃÃ why?

Tags: java, string, unicode, character-encoding

Whats the problem with this code? I made an ISO8859 String. So most of the ÄÖÜ are some krypooutput. Thats fine. But how to Convert them back to normal chars (UTF8 or something)?

```
    String s = new String("Üü?öäABC".getBytes(), "ISO-8859-15");

    System.out.println(s);
    //ÃÃŒ?Ã¶Ã€ABC => ok(?)
    System.out.println(new String(s.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-15"));
    //ÃÂÃÅ?ÃÂ¶Ãâ¬ABC => ok(?)
    System.out.println(new String(s.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
    //ÃÃŒ?Ã¶Ã€ABC => huh?
```

Comment: Assuming that "krypooutput" means output from a cryptographic function, why are you trying to convert it into "normal chars". That is insecure, for it would result in loss of data. If you need a human readable form of that data, use hex-encoding or url-encoding.

Comment: There is no such thing as "ISO8859 String" in Java. See http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: Then how to convert an input String like "ÃÃŒ?Ã¶Ã€ABC" to normal? (if I know that the string is from an ISO8859 file).

Comment: So, you have a IOS8859 file? Then you need to specify the encoding when reading string from it, for example, via `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: @axtavt: ... no thats not the problem. I know InputStreamReader and know how to read a file in another coding. The problem is: I cant use InputStream AND i have an ISO8859 String, NOT FILE. The problem is like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117624/get-filename-as-utf-8-a-u-o-is-always

Comment: @Lissy: the first serious issue you have is that you're using non-ASCII characters in your *.java* source file and this is delusional. Sadly Java doesn't specify the encoding of its source code files and you'll discover a world of hurt if you use non-ASCII chars in *.java* source files.  String should be externalized and Java programmers using non-ASCII characters in .java comments should be shot to death. This is fine in toyish environment where you have one developer working with one IDE and one VCS on one OS but as soon as you mix developers, you'll discover pain.  Externalize your Strings.

Comment: @Lissy - what you are saying doesn't make sense.  in java, you can _only_ ever have a utf-16 String.  please give more details of your problem.  you linked to another stackoverflow question, is your problem related to filenames?

Comment: @Syntax: I disagree with you, partially: Non-ASCII characters can be used when the build-system (and usually IDE config files) are configured to use a specified encoding. It works very nicely in this case. But if those conditions are not met, then it can become nasty.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: ah ah, only partially :)  Build system *and* VCS *and* any single external tool you may want to use to process/parse/diff your source files.  We've been bit so many times, so many developers suffered pain, that we now have our build process refuse to compile any *.java* source file that is not 100% ASCII.  Of course such problems are way less problematic with languages where the encoding of the source file is set in stone in specs (like in Google's Go language).

Answer (score 7):

A construct such as `new String("Üü?öäABC".getBytes(), "ISO-8859-15");` is *almost always* an error.

What you're doing here is taking a `String` object, getting the corresponding `byte[]` in the **platform default encoding** and re-interpreting it as ISO-8859-15 to convert it back to a `String`.

**If** the platform default encoding happens to be ISO-8859-15 (or near enough to make no difference for this particular `String`, for example ISO-8859-1), then it is a no-op (i.e. it has no real effect).

In all other cases it will **most likely** destroy the `String`.

**If** you try to "fix" a `String`, then you're probably too late: if you have to use a specific encoding to read data, then you should use it **at the point where binary data is converted to `String` data**. For example if you read from an `InputStream`, you need to pass the **correct** encoding to the constructor of the `InputStreamReader`.

Trying to fix the problem "after the fact" will be

1. harder to do and
2. often not even possible (because decoding a `byte[]` with the wrong encoding can be a destructive operation).

Answer (score 7):

I hope this will solve your problem.

```
String readable = "äöüÄÖÜßáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙñÑ";

try {
    String unreadable = new String(readable.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-15");
    // unreadable -> Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃÃÃÃÃ¡Ã©Ã­Ã³ÃºÃÃÃÃÃÃ Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹ÃÃÃÃÃÃ±Ã
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // handle error
}
```

And:

```
String unreadable = "Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃÃÃÃÃ¡Ã©Ã­Ã³ÃºÃÃÃÃÃÃ Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹ÃÃÃÃÃÃ±Ã";

try {
    String readable = new String(unreadable.getBytes("ISO-8859-15"), "UTF-8");
    // readable -> äöüÄÖÜßáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙñÑ
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Jooce, I tried the same, it seems it is working fine, thank you for this

Answer (score 4):

```
String s = new String("Üü?öäABC".getBytes(), "ISO-8859-15"); //bug
```

All this code does is corrupt data. It transcodes UTF-16 data to the system encoding (whatever that is) and the takes those bytes, pretends they're valid ISO-8859-15 and transcodes them to UTF-16.

> Then how to convert an input String like "ÃÃŒ?Ã¶Ã€ABC" to normal? (if I know that the string is from an ISO8859 file).

The correct way to perform this operation would be like this:

```
byte[] iso859_15 = { (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xbc, 0x3f,
  (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xb6, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xa4, 0x41, 0x42,
         0x43 };
String utf16 = new String(iso859_15, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15"));
```

Strings in Java are always UTF-16. All other encodings must be represented using the `byte` type.

*Now, if you use `System.out` to output the resultant string, that might not appear correctly, but that is a different transcoding issue. For example, the [Windows console](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html) default encoding doesn't match the system encoding. The encoding used by `System.out` must match the encoding of the device receiving the data. You should also take care to ensure that you are [reading your source files](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_sourcefiles) with the same encoding your editor is using.*

*To understand how treatment of character data varies between languages, read [this](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/04/i18n-comparing-character-encoding-in-c.html).*

Comment: I should not that the byte array contains `ÃÃŒ?Ã¶Ã€ABC` encoded as ISO-8859-15, which is perhaps not the String the OP wants. `Üü?öäABC` encoded as ISO-8859-15 would be the array `{ 0x22, (byte) 0xdc, (byte) 0xfc, 0x3f, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0xe4, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x22 }`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way with String output (I created a method to do this):

```
public static String (String input){
String output = "";
try {
    /* From ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 */
    output = new String(input.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
    /* From UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 */
    output = new String(input.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return output;
```

}

```
// Example
input = "Música";
output = "MÃºsica";
```

it works!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Java Strings are internally always stored as UTF16 arrays (and as UTF8 in the class file after compliation), so you can't simply interpret a string as if it was a byte array. If you want to create a byte array from a string in a certain encoding, you must first convert into this encoding:

```
byte[] b = "Üü?öäABC".getBytes("ISO-8859-15");

System.out.println(new String(b, "ISO-8859-15")); // will be ok
System.out.println(new String(b, "UTF-8")); // will look garbled
```

Answer (score 1):

this solution work for me i hope that will  help you

```
String s1 = "l'Ã©pargne";
String s2 = new String(s1.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to provide the extended set of characters in order to validate converted strings from ISO-8859-1 into utf-8.

```
@Test
public void testEnc() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String isoString = "Ã¤Ã¶";
    String utfString = new String(isoString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8");
    boolean validConvertion = containsSpecialCharacter(utfString);
    assertTrue(validConvertion);
}

public boolean containsSpecialCharacter(String str) {
    String[] readable = new String[] { "Ã", "Ã", "Ñ", "Ò", "Ó", "Ô", "Õ", "Ö", "×", "Ø", "Ù", "Ú", "Û", "Ü", "Ã", "Þ", "ß",
            "à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä", "å", "æ", "ç", "è", "é", "ê", "ë", "ì", "í", "î", "ï", "ð", "ñ", "ò", "ó", "ô", "õ", "ö",
            "÷", "ø", "ù", "ú", "û", "ü", "ý", "þ", "ÿ" };
    for (String st : readable) {
        if (str.contains(st)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```